# Ada - Convert a function to a procedure

Tags: string, ada

My function that I would like to convert to a procedure subprogram is the following:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Test is
         
   function Split_String (S : in String) return String is         
      Mid : Positive := 1 + (S'Length / 2);         
   begin          
      return S (Mid .. S'Last);   
   end Split_String;

   S : String (1 .. 7);
   Length : Natural;

begin
   Put ("Type a string containing 7 characters: ");
   Get_Line (S, Length);
   Put("The other half of the string is: ");
   Put(Split_String(S(1 .. Length)));    
end Test;
```

What does does is that it types the other last half of the the string that the user has typed in

For instance if you type: **Bagels** it will type out "els"

If you type something with an odd amount of characters, like **Stack** it will type out "ack".

So my question is that how do I convert this function subprogram to a procedure subprogram while ONLY having one string parameter.

I know that you have to do

```
procedure Split_String (S : in out String) is    
begin
   ....
```

But how do I return S(Mid .. S'Last)?

Comment: Since Ada strings are fixed length objects you cannot modify the parameter passed in to be a string of fewer characters.

Comment: So I can't create a procedure?

Comment: Not using the Ada String type. If you want to do that then consider using a bounded string type or an unbounded string type.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [*Fixed-Length String Handling*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html). In the example below, `Split_String` first finds the `Last` non-blank character and then finds the desired `Index`. [`Move`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html#p43) copies the corresponding range of characters *in situ*. The default `Pad` is the `Space` character, but you can change it to see the effect.

```
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Fixed_Test is

   procedure Split_String (S : in out String) is
      Last  : constant Natural := Index_Non_Blank (S, Backward);
      Index : constant Natural := Last / 2 + 1;
   begin
      Move (S (Index .. Last), S);
   end Split_String;

   procedure Print (S : String) is
      T : String := S;
   begin
      Put (S & " -> ");
      Split_String (T);
      Put_Line (T);
   end Print;

begin
   Print ("Bagels ");
   Print ("Stack  ");
   Print ("1234567");
   Print ("123456 ");
   Print ("12345  ");
   Print ("1234   ");
   Print ("123    ");
   Print ("12     ");
   Print ("1      ");
end Fixed_Test;
```

Console:

```
Bagels  -> els    
Stack   -> ack    
1234567 -> 4567   
123456  -> 456    
12345   -> 345    
1234    -> 34     
123     -> 23     
12      -> 2      
1       -> 1
```